# NPM and yarn.lock

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Since NPM v7 the official [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install) state the following about `npm install` (emphasis mine):

> This command installs a package and any packages that it depends on. If the package has a package-lock, or an npm shrinkwrap file, or a **yarn lock** file, the installation of dependencies will be driven by that

I was trying to find more information about `npm install` behavior with the `yarn.lock` present, but didn't find much. [This](https://justfrontendthings.com/post/npm-7-now-standard) blog post states:

> With the new `package-lock.json` file we'll unlock the ability to do deterministically reproducible builds. It should now include everything npm needs to install the packages needed. Before npm 7 `yarn.lock` was ignored by npm, but this is no longer the case. It can now use it to keep itself up to date with the package tree.

GitHub [blog](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/):

> In prior versions, the yarn.lock files were ignored, the npm CLI can now use yarn.lock as the source of package metadata and resolution guidance. If a `yarn.lock` file is present, then npm will also keep it up-to-date with the contents of the package tree.

But neither of them gives a clear picture of what actually happens when I run `npm install` with `yarn.lock`.

I'd like to get a grasp on it:

- Can I run `yarn` locally to generate `yarn.lock` and reproduce the package tree on CI with `npm install`?
- What exactly happens when I run `npm install` with `yarn.lock`? Does it get updated? Can it be run with (sort of) `--frozen-lockfile`? The [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci) command doesn't mention `yarn.lock` at all.
- Does it support both `v1` and `berry`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I run yarn locally to generate yarn.lock and reproduce the package tree on CI with npm install?

No, you still need a `package-lock.json` file if you want to reproduce the package tree using npm v7. v7 only uses the yarn.lock file as a **source of package metadata** and **resolution guidance**.

This is because npm v7 generates the lockfiles with the a new `lockFileVersion: 2` (backward compatible) to improve performance and allow reproducible builds with deterministic tree shape; it also tries to reduce reading from `package.json` file for metadata.

> What exactly happens when I run npm install with yarn.lock? Does it get updated? Can it be run with (sort of) --frozen-lockfile? The npm ci command doesn't mention yarn.lock at all.

Yes, the `yarn.lock` file will be updated and npm will still create a `package-lock.json` file, and if a `package-lock.json` file is present, it’ll be used as the authoritative definition of the tree shape to create.

As per [this NPM blog post](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/621733939456933888/npm-v7-series-why-keep-package-lockjson), the reason they don't support yarn.lock file yet is

> One common question we’ve gotten a few times now, once we announce that npm v7 will include support for yarn.lock files, is “Why keep package-lock.json at all, then? Why not just use yarn.lock only?”

> The simple answer is: because yarn.lock doesn’t fully address npm’s needs, and relying on it exclusively would limit our ability to produce optimal package installs or add features in the future.

Finally,

> Does it support both v1 and berry?

This is not clear, and is implied to change for `berry` as yarn uses a combination of `yarn.lock` file and yarn version to guarantee deterministic resolution.

I suggest reading [this blogpost](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/catching-up-with-package-lockfile-changes-in-npm-v7/) along with the above post from [npm](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/621733939456933888/npm-v7-series-why-keep-package-lockjson) for more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have done so much research and it seemed further document searching wouldn't alleviate your uncertainty, why not take a future step to take a look at the source code? Don't be afraid to read code

So, I did a superficial search on the repo https://github.com/npm/cli and found [this file](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/workspaces/arborist/lib/shrinkwrap.js) can answer your question

For takeaway,

> Can I run `yarn` locally to generate `yarn.lock` and reproduce the package tree on CI with npm install?

Yes, unless you use some protocols only attributed to `berry` and unsupported by npm

> What exactly happens when I run npm install with yarn.lock? Does it get updated? Can it be run with (sort of) --frozen-lockfile? The npm ci command doesn't mention yarn.lock at all.

1. When you run `npm i`, `yarn.lock` will get updated. At least it will make some formatting changes and overwrite the registry URL. If `npm` cannot find the resolved version of a package or the resolved version isn't valid, it will get it from the registry and update in both `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock`.
2. `npm ci` requires `package-lock.json` otherwise it will exit immediately

> Does it support both v1 and berry?

it don't work well with `berry`. `npm` will overwrite the `yarn.lock` with the format of yarn lockfile v1

Answer (score 1):

This doc should help explain a bit: [https://blog.npmjs.org/post/621733939456933888/npm-v7-series-why-keep-package-lockjson.html#:~:text=While%20npm%20uses%20the%20yarn,t%20ideal%20in%20these%20cases](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/621733939456933888/npm-v7-series-why-keep-package-lockjson.html#:%7E:text=While%20npm%20uses%20the%20yarn,t%20ideal%20in%20these%20cases).

This link explains a bit on yarn and npm interacting tho on the idea that your switching from npm to yarn, so kinda the opposite but a list of comparison commands (CI) that could be interesting to view: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/

I don't know much about the difference other then Yarn install faster and the packages are built a little different. Couldn't find a doc that explains switching to npm. Delete the yarn.lock before starting npm. Otherwise, see above answer.